# Mobile First Json store push BUG

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I would like to underline an issue in cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore
during some investigation I notice that in method **sendResourceRequest**  on **PushInstance** data is not sent with

```
resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest('adapters/' + invocationData.adapter + '/' + invocationData.procedure,  WLResourceRequest.POST);
resourceRequest.send().then(ipOpts.onSuccess, ipOpts.onFailure);
```

according to me should become:

```
resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest('adapters/' + invocationData.adapter + '/' + invocationData.procedure,  WLResourceRequest.POST);
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters({ "params":"['" + JSON.stringify(collectionDocument) + "']" });
```

I need to use it in a really important project, is it possible to fix as soon as possible?

Regards.

Daniele

Answer (score 0):

If you require changes/fixes in the JSONStore plug-in by IBM you need to open a PMR for IBM to correct it and provide you with an iFix.

Answer (score 0):

in  my opinion you are using adapter library (not JSON Store).

I have one question:

why in the first call (send) you do not configure parameters like in second one (sendFormParameters) ?

I have multiple example working like this (try with POST instead of GET):

```
    var submitOrderRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/BPMAdapter/startProcess", WLResourceRequest.GET);('params', [JSON.stringify(cartDataApp)]);
    submitOrderRequest.send().then(function(result) {
            orderId = result.responseJSON.data.piid;
        }, function(error) {
        console.log("---> Error calling submitOrder procedure in BPMadapter" + error);
    });
```